# Facebook C# SDK Silverlight Sample App doesnt work

Tags: c#, silverlight, facebook-c#-sdk, sample

Hallo,

I am new to silverlight development and I would like to run a sample from facebooksdk.codeplex.com called CSSilverightinBrowser. It works (It gets an authorization and it logs me into the Facebook) if I host it in cassini localhost, but if I try to refer to my localhost address (http://localhost:18031) from Facebook it keeps reloading itself. And If I host it in IIS on localhost I get error "This webpage has a redirect loop". Is something wrong with the application or do I have some wrong settings ? Eventually is there any other start-up that you would recommend to me to learn how to connect silverlight with facebook's SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, have you configured the Web.Config for the new locations (localhost:18031) as well as set things up in Facebook? When I last checked, I know the documentation is not 100% up to date, but you should be able to get a good idea of what you need to do by looking at the docs.

[Check here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Facebook%20App%20Setup%20for%20the%20WP7%20and%20Silverlight%20Samples&referringTitle=Silverlight%204%20In%20Browser%20Sample) and make sure you have Facebook setup correctly (and set any of the new options under advanced to disabled).

Also [go here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation) and skip to the Web.Config section. Not all the values here are applicable, but this section will explain what the various settings are in our config settings (also we only have one config setting now.. we used to have 2).

If that doesn't help respond here with some more details on what errors you are getting, and I will try to help you a little more.

Comment: Hi thanks for respond, I havent found any settings in my Web.Config. There is only following code: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>  
The settings on the facebook work fine.

Comment: I guess it's time for me to download that sample and look at how it has evolved...

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to get back to this.. there is a new version of the SDK.. have you tried the sample there?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem earlier today with CSASPNETFacebookApp, and it turns out the issue was that I hadn't enabled OAuth 2.0 for Canvas in my Facebook application settings. Hopefully this helps.

Cheers,
Kevin